# Keyboard not working with emulator anymore

Tags: android-emulator

I am running the Visual Studio Emulator for Android. Everything was working fine, but then it notified me that an update was available, so I downloaded and installed the latest version. Now when I launch any device, the device doesn't detect input from my keyboard. Are there any settings that could have been reverted in the update that I would need to check? Is there somewhere I can get the historic version from so I can downgrade to the previous version to see if this fixes the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft kindly responded to me with the solution to this as there is an issue with the latest release. I had to add EN-US language to my system (regional settings) - no need to set it as active, just install it. This fixes the issue. They will aim to fix this with the next release.